# Winding number and homotopic paths (Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, winding-number

I know that if $\Omega$ is open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $\gamma_1$,$\gamma_2$ are two homotopic paths such that $\gamma^*_1$,$\gamma^*_2 \subset \Omega$ then $\forall \alpha$$\in$ $\mathbb{C}\setminus \Omega$  $\quad$$n(\gamma_1,\alpha)=n(\gamma_2,\alpha)$.

I also know that the winding number equals $0$ in the unbounded component of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\gamma^*_i$. But if $\gamma^*_i\subset \Omega$ why $n(\gamma_i,\alpha)=0$? Is not true that $\mathbb{C}\setminus\Omega \subset A$ where $A$ denotes de unbounded component of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \gamma^*_i$ ?

I'd be very thankful if someone clarified these concepts.

Comment: It is not true that in general $\Bbb{C} \setminus \Omega \subseteq A$. A counterexample follows: take $\Omega$ to be an open annulus, and $\gamma_i$ be non-nullhomotopic circles inside the annulus $\Omega$. For an image, see https://haggisthesheep.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/linebundle21.png

Comment: @Abellan: What does $\gamma^*$ mean? Is it the image of $\gamma$?

Comment: Thanks, the counterexample was pretty obvious . Silly me!